# accept statement returns two different values in two different codes which looks similer?

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I am new to C and sockets programming and am trying to do a simple client server application.

I have found that whenever I try to connect to client from server with the following code and the  **accept** statement returns 0 to **connectfd** and when I try to send a message from client its not reaching server,

```
if(connectfd = (accept(sockfd , (struct sockaddr *)NULL , NULL)) < 0)
{
    printf("problem while connection to client\n");
    return(0);  
}
```

But when I try the code below instead of the code which is above **accept** statement returns 4 as a value to **connectfd** 
and the client server communication happens perfectly

```
connectfd=accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)NULL,NULL);
if(connectfd<0)

{
    printf("server acccept failed...\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Can anyone give an explanation for this?

Comment: Seems like you are new to debugging too.  If a compound expression fails, break it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your parentheses are in the wrong place:

```
if(connectfd = (accept(sockfd , (struct sockaddr *)NULL , NULL)) < 0)
```

Should be:

```
if ((connectfd = accept(sockfd , (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL)) < 0)
```

Because of [C operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence), where `<` has higher precedence than `=`, what is being assigned to `connectfd` is the result of the comparison between the return value of `accept` and `0`, not the return value of `accept` as you intend.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(connectfd = (accept(sockfd , (struct sockaddr *)NULL , NULL)) < 0)
```

will assign "(accept(...) < 0)" to "connectfd"

you should write

```
if((connectfd = accept(sockfd , (struct sockaddr *)NULL , NULL)) < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the precedence rules,

```
if (a = b < c)
```

is interpreted as an assignment of `b < c` to `a`, not as a comparisong of `a = b` with `c`.

The consequence of this is that you have to place parentheses, as [Sean already writes in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21022812/296974).